# How to efficiently apply a two variable function to data.frame( or matrix) elements - to fill an output matrix?

Tags: r, function, matrix

I am trying to find more efficient way(s) to fill an output matrix by applying a function to elements in a `data.frame`. I experimented with the `apply()` family functions and the `outer()` function but couldn't make them work.

Maybe someone here might be able to help? Here's a simplified version of my script. Thanks!

```
set.seed(192)
n = 1000
distMatrix <- matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n) 

# Co-ordinates
coord <- data.frame(x = runif(n,min=0,max=n),
                    y = runif(n,min=0,max=n))

# Distance Function
distance <- function(A,B) { sqrt( (A['x']-B['x'])^2 + (A['y']-B['y'])^2  ) }

# Fill distMatrix -- this part could use better programming. Note that I am only
# filling the upper triangular part of distMatrix.
for (r in 1:(n-1)) {
    for (c in (r+1):n) {
        distMatrix[[r,c]] <- distance(coord[r,],coord[c,])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
distFun <- function(A,B) 
  sqrt(
    (coord[A, "x"] - coord[B, "x"]) ^ 2 + 
    (coord[A, "y"] - coord[B, "y"]) ^ 2  
  )
distMatrix <- outer(1:nrow(coord), 1:nrow(coord), distFun)
```

Notice that we need to pass `outer` two vectors.  Here we use the indeces of the rows of the data frame.  `outer` then produces two new vectors that together represent every possible combination of our original vectors, and passes those to our function.  Our function then pulls the relevant coordinates for our calculations (here `coord` is assumed to be defined ahead of the function).

One key thing to understand when using `outer` is that our function is called only once.  `outer` just computes the vector inputs assuming our function is vectorized, and then applies the corresponding dimensions to the result.

Also, look at `?dist`:

```
dist(coord)
```

Try it with a smaller matrix (maybe 10 by 10) to see the result.

Comment: My actual system had three instances of nested for loops, and it was for 1000 x 1000 sized matrices. I implemented outer() and the runtime is down to 10 mins from 40+mins! Thanks much @BrodieG.